# How do I change the canvas size on expression blend sketchflow?

Tags: expression, expression-blend, sketchflow

How do I change the default canvas size, it's simply too small for my prototype.

Help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools > Options > SketchFlow : set the Default sizes to what you want.

Comment: You can also resize your existing screen by dragging the adorners in the lower right corner of the "page" area.